# Как добавить пропущенные индексы даты?

Tags: python, pandas, дата, datetime

Есть фрейм, индексами которого являются даты:

```
Id          Close
2021-09-16  148.789993
2021-09-17  146.059998
2021-09-20  142.940002
```

Как дополнить его строками с индексами с интервалом каждый день с `NaN` значениями?

```
Id          Close
2021-09-16  148.789993
2021-09-17  146.059998
2021-09-18  NaN
2021-09-19  NaN
2021-09-20  142.940002
```

---

Доп. вопрос: только начинаю заниматься временными рядами и, как можно заметить, столкнулся с проблемой в пробелах в данных. Я собираюсь использовать метод `.interpolate(method='linear')`, чтобы восстановить пробелы. Возможно такой способ предобработки данных на практике неверен для этой задачи, и вы могли бы посоветовать другой?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
d = (d
     .set_index("Id")
     .reindex(pd.date_range(d["Id"].min(), d["Id"].max()))
     .reset_index())
```

результат:

```
In [25]: d
Out[25]:
       index       Close
0 2021-09-16  148.789993
1 2021-09-17  146.059998
2 2021-09-18         NaN
3 2021-09-19         NaN
4 2021-09-20  142.940002
```